# Birthday workflow

Tags: list, workflow, email

I created a list with two columns. One is the *Name* and the other is a Date Column which means the day of the *Name*´s Birthday.

What I´m trying to do is, when the birthday day comes, sends an email to me!

How can I do this? It´s a workflow right? But there I can't find this rule!

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

I Think you can easily work out this by creating a SharePoint Designer List workflow where you need to give a condition like if Date (column value) equal to Today then send an email to your self (your email id) and select "Run Automatically" when you are publishing it.

Answer (score 2):

You basically need 2 workflows that will end up triggering each other to create a loop.

The workflows would check to see if the date the workflow is being executed is the same as the birthday. If it is, email the user, if it isn't wait 24 hours, update a trigger field in your list and end.  This updating of the trigger will cause the other workflow to start and do the same thing.

In SP 2013, there will be loop actions, so this should finally be easier to accomplish.